# CSV to JSON with dynamic objects name fields

Tags: c#, choetl

I have a number of CSV files which I desire to translate to JSON files using [Cinchoo](https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL). I'll need to rename the fields (and convert them into the desired data type).  I'm having trouble renaming the fields.

**Dummy input file:**

```
VE NUMMER;VE NAAM;EFFECTDATUM;EINDDATUM
123;abc;20221001;
124;def;20221001;
125;ter;20221001;
126;ddf;20221001;
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
{
    "Id": 123,
    "Name": "abc",
    "Date": "20221001"
},
{
    "Id": 124,
    "Name": "def",
    "Date": "20221001"
}, ...
]
```

I've tried

- Using the `BeforeRecordWrite` event, but this is throwing errors when renaming the property
- Using a custom `ContractResolver` but this seems to be ignored
- Using a custom `JsonConverter` but this seems to be ignored

```
using ChoETL;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        QuickConversion();

    }

    private static void QuickConversion()
    {
        using var r = new ChoCSVReader("./Data./DummyFile.CSV")
               .WithFirstLineHeader()
               .WithDelimiter(";")
               .WithEOLDelimiter("\r\n")
               .MayHaveQuotedFields();

        using var w = new ChoJSONWriter(Console.Out)
           //.JsonSerializationSettings(settings =>
           //{
           //    settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
           //    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
           //    settings.MaxDepth = 2;
           //    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
           //    settings.ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver("VE NUMMER", "ID");
           //})
           .WithJSONConverter(new CustomConverter())
        .UseJsonSerialization();

        w.Write(r);
    }
}

public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;
    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver("VE NUMMER", "ID");
    }
}
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public string SourcePropertyName { get; set; }
    public string TargetPropertyName { get; set; }
    public CustomContractResolver(string sourcePropertyName, string targetPropertyName)
    {
        SourcePropertyName = sourcePropertyName;
        TargetPropertyName = targetPropertyName;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        Console.WriteLine(property.PropertyName);

        if (property.PropertyName == SourcePropertyName)
        {
            property.PropertyName = TargetPropertyName;
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is possible to specify the fields already during import:

```
using var r = new ChoCSVReader("./Data./DummyFile.CSV")
        .WithFields("Id", "Name", "Date")
        .WithFirstLineHeader(true)
        .WithDelimiter(";")
        .WithEOLDelimiter("\r\n")
        .MayHaveQuotedFields();
```

Then you do not need a `CustomConverter`

Comment: I unfortunately can't change the name of the input fields. They are provided by a 3rd party with their respective field names. 
Using with Fields (or withField) requires to match with the source from my understanding of it.

Comment: You can use this method if you know the order of the columns.
`.WithFirstLineHeader(true)` ignore the header and 
`.WithFields("Id", "Name", "Date")` means, that the first column will read as "Id" and so on.
You do not need to change the file

Comment: works like a charm with ```.WithFirstLineHeader(true).WithFields(new string[] { "Id", "Name" })```